# How does ImageSource return bytes to the application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to implement my own subclass of `ImageSource`. Xamarin Forms has `FileImageSource`, `UriImageSource` and several other subclasses of `ImageSource`, but none of them meets my needs.

To see how to implement an `ImageSource` subclass, I looked at implementation of `FileImageSource` on github (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FileImageSource.cs)

I expected to find that the subclass would override one or more `ImageSource` methods to actually read the image file and provide the bytes from the file to the calling platform. But source code of FileImageSource contains no such thing! In fact, they use the File only to override `ImageSource.IsEmpty`. How can this be? If an image is contained in a file, you need to read the file to display this image, don't you?

What am I missing? And if I want to implement my own subclass of ImageSource, how can my sublass return image data to the platform?

**Edit**
Thank you to everyone who proposed solving the issue in a different way and inquiring why exactly existing ImageSource subclasses do not serve my needs.

Even if there is a different way to solve my immediate issue, **from an educational perspective** it is still interesting to know how Xamarin Forms displays an image file without reading the file. The source code for FileImageSource is quite short and does not appear to use the file, other than to implement IsEmpty. This will bug me until I know how this works.

Comment: `If an image is contained in a file, you need to read the file to display this image?` In that case the app accessible file is read and displayed by the OS/native widget, no need to add another layer of code

Comment: "none of them meets my needs" - perhaps if you explained what shortcoming of ImageSource you are trying to fix we could make a suggestion?

Comment: as @SushiHangover points out, the underlying platform image controls know how to load an image from a file.  The FileImageSource isn't doing anything beyond passing a path to the native control.  You might want to look at FFImageLoading which has some additional ImageSource types, they might shed more light onto how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Resolve the issue using converters]**

Instead of creating a new ImageSource, you could create a [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) (if you are working with bindings).

So if you have something like a byte array, and you want that to be shown as an image, you can do the conversion from byte array into a [StreamImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.streamimagesource?view=xamarin-forms)

**[EDIT: Knowing how it works]**

If you want to know how it works internally and how it transforms the File into the actual Image, you will have to go deeper into the code, and check the platform implementations.
For example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers) you have the android renderers. You will find the IImageSourceHandler.cs and the FontImageSourceHandler and the FileImageSourceHandler and so on.

Comment: Even if I could solve my immediate issue with a converter, this still does not explain how XamarinForms displays an image file without any code to actually read the file.

Comment: In the link that you posted you can see that at the top it displays  
```[TypeConverter(typeof(FileImageSourceConverter))]


 public sealed class FileImageSource : ImageSource```


And then you can access that class 
[here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FileImageSourceConverter.cs)

Comment: I don't see FileImageSourceConverter.cs reading the image file either. Something needs to be reading the actual image from disk. And it looks like nothing reads it.

Comment: If you want to know that, probably you will have to go deeper into the code, and check the platform implementations. For example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers) you have the android renderers. You will find the IImageSourceHandler.cs and the FontImageSourceHandler and the  FileImageSourceHandler and so on.

Comment: Thank you! So renderers get the actual bytes from a file, from the internet, or wherever. If you want to write this up as an answer I will gladly accept it.